# Working locally after cloning Craft 3 from Hyperlane

Tags: craft3, database, config

I'm trying out the recommended Hyperlane hosting with Craft CMS. After installing on Hyperlane, I then clone the repo on to my local machine and run 'composer install'. That runs fine, and I create a .env file with my db connection details in it.

What happens next is I go to install on my machine by viewing the admin panel but I get the following:

```
Database Connection Error – craft\errors\DbConnectException
Craft CMS can’t connect to the database with the credentials in config/db.php.
↵
Caused by: Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
Connection::dsn cannot be empty.
in C:\Users\clive\OneDrive\Desktop\repos\projectname\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\Connection.php at line 602
```

If I add the database details to config/db.php myself, it works fine. It just seems to be a problem with fetching them from .env.

I'm using WAMP on Windows and have numerous Craft 3 projects already running. This same project is fine if I install locally from scratch. It's just when I start by cloning from Hyperlane.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. The config/db.php cloned from Hyperlane refers to different env variable names than those used within my .env file. Changing the names in config/db.php solved the issue.

Before:

```
return [
    'driver' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
    'server' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_NAME'),
    'schema' => getenv('DB_SCHEMA'),
    'tablePrefix' => getenv('DB_TABLE_PREFIX'),
    'port' => getenv('DB_PORT')
];
```

After:

```
return [
    'driver' => getenv('DB_DRIVER'),
    'server' => getenv('DB_SERVER'), // changed
    'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'), // changed
    'schema' => getenv('DB_SCHEMA'),
    'tablePrefix' => getenv('DB_TABLE_PREFIX'),
    'port' => getenv('DB_PORT')
];
```

Comment: Remember to add the file to .gitignore...

Comment: Thanks for this! Bloody Hyperlane changing these env variables... cost me ages.